# share home directory by samba in ubuntu

Tags: server, samba, file-sharing

I have installed samba on my Ubuntu server.
I do changes on smb.config and I can connect from my windows to the share file which I create in a path /srv/samba/share with using [share] part and creating that folder
after that I wanted to share my home directory
I changed [homes] with some options to be accessible and I use smbpasswd to create a user and password.
when I open my network I can see the share folder which is accessible and homes folder which is shared but I can not access to the homes folder.
how can I open it and where I need that user which I create by smbpasswd.
It is not accessible.
Please help me to share my home directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[Ubuntu]
Path = /home
Available = yes
Valid users = ubuntu
Read only = no
Browsable = yes
Public = yes
Writable = yes
```